# couldn't find main class

Tags: java, netbeans, jar, manifest, executable-jar

I have 3 GUI forms

- main1.java
- main2.java
- main3.java

with main methods. One in `package1` other two are in `package2`.

I have set the `package1.main1` as main class in project configuration. After clean build, when I sent my `.jar` file to my friend, it shows an error- `couldn't find main class`. I checked in the manifest file, it seems all correct and also there is not `package2` inside the jar.

Please help me to fix this.

FYI, I'm using netbeans7.2

Comment: How is your friend trying to run the application?

Comment: by double clicking the .jar :)

Comment: Please edit your question with the contents of the jar and the content of the manifest file

Comment: Which class has the **main()** method in all the 3 packages? That should be the main package. An application should only have one main method, not three.

Comment: As you said 'there is not `package2` inside the jar'. It should be present if there is a dependancy.

Comment: @mtk now there are all contents in tha jar. waiting for my friend to re-run it. I'll write to you with results. Thank you so much for the heads up.

Comment: @It'sYourFault same jar runs well in my system. i just have to figure out how to run on my friend's. I know about the main()s. :) I have configured to run main1.java as Main class in my manifest.

Answer (score 0):

I think its still some inconsistency in your jar.
I would suggest the following:

run the following command in order to track the content of your jar:

```
jar tf YOUR_JAR_FILE_COMES_HERE
```

After you ensure that all the packages are places correctly and the Main class really exists there 
Double check your MANIFEST.MF file. 
Once the main class is defined correctly here your friend should be able to run `java -jar YOUR_JAR_FILE_COMES_HERE_AGAIN`

Another concert that I would check, On windows file names are case insensitive, while on linux/unix its not the case, you'll have to check the all the uppercases/lowercases are set up correctly.

Hope this helps